# Why are there inconsistencies in type casting (ChangeType, ToString, as) when dynamic is involved?

Tags: c#, nancy

I have a method, that I eventually managed to fit my needs:

```
protected bool TryChangeType(dynamic form)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(form.changeType); // "true"
        // string type = form.changeType as string; // #1
        // string type = Convert.ToString(form.changeType); // #2
        string type = Convert.ChangeType(form.changeType, typeof(String)); // #3

        return type.ToLower() == "true";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

First off, I started with `form.changeType as string` (`#1`) - didn't work, `NullReferenceException`.

Then, I attempted `Convert.ToString` (`#2`) - no success, `RuntimeBinderException`, ambiguous call between `ToString(bool)` and `ToString(DateTime)`.

After some looking around, I found out about `ChangeType` - it worked.

#### Update

The `form` variable is of type: [Nancy.DynamicDictionary](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/DynamicDictionary.cs)

And `form.changeType` is: [Nancy.DynamicDictionaryValue](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/DynamicDictionaryValue.cs)

Why are there such inconsistencies, and what are the differences?

Comment: What type is `form.changeType`? Not `string`, obviously, or `as` would work. Read the [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation to learn why that works. Are you sure you need `dynamic` here anyway? Can't you do it through an interface?

Comment: I suspect that a Nullable is involved.  But come on, throw us a bone, what does form.changeType.GetType() return?

Comment: I don't think `Nullable` can be involved here: when you're dealing with `dynamic`, everything is `object` with special compiler support, but everything being `object` means everything is boxed, and `Nullable<T>` has become plain `T` already. But what *is* the problem cannot be determined from the question, the question badly needs updating if it is to get a good answer.

Comment: See update, added links to classes.